# Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 throws a build error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Recently upgraded to VS 2010 from 2008, the previously built solutions are throwing the following error.

> Error 14 Encountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID 'a5851ea0-2f9a-40b2-a73a-cd7db32f09c5'.  Try pre-importing one of these assemblies

I tried re-installing VS 2010 and it didnot help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the VS 2010 application itself crashing, or does it not like your solution? Can you open VS 2010 by itself? If so, it sounds like it doesn't like some of your references in one or more of your projects. Check the project references. If that doesn't work, start removing projects until you find the offending one.

Comment: VS2010 itself opens fine, sorry for the confusion. And I know which project is causing it. Not sure why and how to resolve it. All references seem fine

Answer (score 0):

This may happen, if you copy-paste-renamed a project file to re-use its settings but didn't changed the project GUID of it. Also could be a project migration error, anyway you will have to manually edit the project file and remove the duplicate references if the project fails to load because of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when migrating 2008 -> 2013.
It was caused that we use same linked AssemblyInfo.cs for all projects in solution.
And only for the assembly that used some COM objects (MSMQ) it seems that it starts looking on referenced assemblies GUID and two of them from our solution...

So when I provide individual AssemblyInfo.cs for projects with unique GUIDs it start working.
Hope this info will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the references to the debug folder.

1. In Visual Studio right click on Project
2. Select Properties
3. Select the references tab.
4. Check to see if any of the references are from the obj\Debug folder and remove them.

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271548/how-to-resolve-the-encountered-multiple-versions-of-the-assembly-with-guid-w?answertab=votes#tab-top).