# How to resolve the "Encountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID '' while converting project from VS 2008 to VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I just converted my project from VS 2008 to VS 2010, here is the error I am getting now :-

> Encountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID ''.  Try
>   pre-importing one of these assemblies.

I already tried to clean solutions, projects, and recompile, close and open again. but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Are any of your references to the debug folder?  If so you'll want to remove them.

EDIT - Since you mentioned COM Object in your comment....

[Assembly error building app - Encountered multiple versions of assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901052/assembly-error-when-building-application)

Looks like it's a bug in VS 2010....

Comment: OH:  Well this might be your issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901052/assembly-error-when-building-application

Comment: Klabranche How to get rid of it?

Comment: I haven't had this issue but the reference to it doesn't seem too promising that it can be fixed without MS fixing it...

Comment: Man I love you! :) Removed all references pointed to debug folder. Tried to compile. Added references again and build succeeded!

Comment: @Sergejs If only I could make everyone fall in love with me so easily. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should try to change .net Framework3.5 to .net Framework4.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your "Assembly.cs" file, there is a GUID in there for your application... for grins, I would just try changing the GUID via generating a new new (don't have VS open for menu action to generate GUIDs, but its there).  Then try to recompile. your project(s) and final application.

Comment: How would i generate GUID? do you mean through c# code.. and copy it and paste in this project??

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Noted some references which looked invalid under References folder in the Solution Explorer. Right Click and Selecte Remove.

Once removed the thing worked just fine.